# Varnish couldn't cache with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, turpentine

I have a magento site running on amazon ec2. My server was **NGINX, CentOS 7**. I installed and configured Varnish and Turpentine to make Varnish work with Magento. I clicked on the button "Download Varnish Config" on Cache Management site in Magento, and then replaced the file `default.vcl` in the **`/etc/varnish`** directory with the file `default.vcl` which generated by Turpentine with . I also restart both NGINX and Varnish to make it works.
But when i try to curl my site, it seems that Varnish doesn't work with my site 
Here is the picture which presents that problem and my default.vcl file which generated by Turpentine
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky5u8.jpg): [image]
**default.vcl**

```
vcl 4.0;
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
backend default {
.host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}
backend admin {
.host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}
acl crawler_acl {
"127.0.0.1";
}
acl debug_acl {
}
/* -- REMOVED
sub generate_session {
if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub(
req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1");
} else {
C{
char uuid_buf [50];
generate_uuid(uuid_buf);
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_REQ_VARNISH_FAKED_SESSION =
{ HDR_REQ, "\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:"};
VRT_SetHdr(ctx,
&VGC_HDR_REQ_VARNISH_FAKED_SESSION,
uuid_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; " + req.http.Cookie;
} else {
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
}
}
sub generate_session_expires {
C{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now);
now_tm.tm_sec += 3600;
mktime(&now_tm);
char date_buf [50];
strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm);
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_RESP_COOKIE_EXPIRES =
{ HDR_RESP, "\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:"};
VRT_SetHdr(ctx,
&VGC_HDR_RESP_COOKIE_EXPIRES,
date_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
-- */
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
}
if (!false || req.http.Authorization ||
req.method !~ "^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS)$" ||
req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
return (pipe);
}
if(false) {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url = req.url;
}
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(.*)//+(.*)", "\1/\2");
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/index\.php/|/media/|/skin/|/js/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
if (req.url ~ "^(/index\.php/|/media/|/skin/|/js/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend_hint = admin;
return (pipe);
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/get(?:Block|FormKey)/") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
!(false || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
return (synth(403, "External ESI requests are not allowed"));
}
}
if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=" && !req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
} else {
return (pipe);
}
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
set req.http.X-Varnish-Static = 1;
return (hash);
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/index\.php/|/media/|/skin/|/js/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
return (pass);
}
if (req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
if (true && req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
if(false) {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url = req.url;
set req.url = req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url;
}
return (hash);
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_hash {
if (true && req.http.X-Varnish-Static) {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
return (lookup);
}
if(false && req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url);
} else {
hash_data(req.url);
}
if (req.http.Host) {
hash_data(req.http.Host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
return (lookup);
}
sub vcl_hit {
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
set beresp.grace = 15s;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Host = bereq.http.host;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-URL = bereq.url;
if (bereq.url ~ "^(/index\.php/|/media/|/skin/|/js/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
unset beresp.http.Vary;
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
return (deliver);
} else {
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
unset beresp.http.Expires;
unset beresp.http.Pragma;
unset beresp.http.Cache;
unset beresp.http.Age;
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
return (deliver);
} else {
if (true &&
bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
set beresp.ttl = 28800s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800";
} elseif (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
bereq.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(bereq.http.Cookie,
"^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
}
if (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
bereq.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
}
set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
regsub(
bereq.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
300s);
if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
return (deliver);
}
} else {
set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
}
}
}
return (deliver);
}
}
sub vcl_deliver {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
if (req.http.Host) {
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
} else {
if(req.http.Host ~ "") {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=";
} else {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
}
}
}
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") {
set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache";
}
if (false || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
} else {
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Host;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-URL;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share your nginx config? Please make sure to remove the hostnames/IPs.

Comment: please check my nginx config file below, ty so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is my nginx config, please check this for me, thank you so much :D

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 54.255.194.210;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic           "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Varnish 4.0.3 try changing to 4.1 - we've seen problems with Varnish 4.0.3 and Centos 7. Or just go back to 3.x.  Otherwise - what errors are you seeing? Are the ESI includes being generated for blocks?

Comment: when i use Chrome to check whether Varnish is working or not,  i reloaded (F5) the page and received the response header with no varnish header field. It's because i had applied varnish config before right?. But the time load for the whole page is still long, it takes about 1,5-2 seconds to load? i don't know why